# Saving Live Video received through Netcat

Tags: streaming, mplayer, netcat

I'm using the following command to stream a video which I receive through Netcat.

```
nc -l -p 5001 | mplayer -fps 31 -cache 1024 -
```

(On Windows CMD)

This command opens the MPlayer and plays the live stream.

Can you tell how to save a copy of this video while playing it live.

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command *tee*:

```
  nc -l -p 5001 | tee  file_containing_the_video.mp4 | mplayer -fps 31 -cache 1024 -
```

if the format you are receiving is mp4. Change it as needed. From [the Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee):

```
  tee - read from standard input and write to standard output **and** files
```

(emphasis mine). This means *tee* simultaneously sends its input to both standard output (from which we pipe it to *mplayer*), and to a file, where you store it.